# Injecting controller into SignalR Hubs using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, signalr, simple-injector

I want to inject a singleton controller into my hubs using Simple Injector.

I've already tried the following but I'm getting status 500 as a response now.

EventDataHub :

```cs
public class EventDataHub : Hub
{
    private static IEventDataController _dataController;
    
    public EventDataHub(IEventDataController dataController)
    {
        _dataController = dataController;
    }
    
    public void Subscribe(string signal)
    {
        _dataController.Subscribe(signal, Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

Startup:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();
    
        var hybridLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
                    lifestyleSelector: () => HttpContext.Current != null,
                    trueLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle(),
                    falseLifestyle: new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());
    
        container.Register<IEventDataController, EventDataController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<IHub, EventDataHub>(hybridLifestyle);
    
        container.Verify();
    
        var activator = new SimpleInjectorHubActivator(container);
        
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => activator);
    
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Hub activator:

```
public class SimpleInjectorHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    
    public SimpleInjectorHubActivator(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    
    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (IHub)_container.GetInstance(descriptor.HubType);
    }
}
```

The `Subscribe` method seems to be unreachable from the client side. The hub constructor is executed.

Exception stack:

> [MissingMethodException: no parameterless constructor defined for this object]
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
> publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
> skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
> Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> +206    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11

**Edit:**

Moving the DI configuration from Startup.cs to global.asax throws this exception:

> [ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null. Parametername:
> s]    System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s) +11377176
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse(JsonSerializer
> serializer, String json) +63
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data,
> JsonSerializer serializer) +21
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest
> request, String connectionId, String data) +40
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClass64_1.b__5()
> +34    Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +28
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +92
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +58

Comment: Please find the raised exception and show all the details of this exception in your question.

Comment: The SignalR application doesn't crash. The exception stack I've included is inside the 500 response.

Comment: From the stacktrace it becomes clear that SignalR is using its `DefaultHubActivator` instead of your `SimpleInjectorHubActivator`.

Comment: Please take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/232) to find out how to integrate Simple Injector with SignalR.

Comment: I have difficulties extracting the concluded information. Is it really necessary to implement `SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher`? Why is registering the custom activator not working?

Comment: Show the constructors for `EventDataController`. Also, is that a Web API or MVC controller? Or just some other class?

Comment: It's just another class. Constructor is parameterless and only gets the client context from the hub. `Clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventDataHub>().Clients;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

`container.Verify()` is breaking the registration of the `IHubActivator`. So it has to be called either afterwards, or never.

Additionally I removed the container registration for `IHub`, as it works without now. (I added it because `container.Register<IEventDataController, EventDataController>(Lifestyle.Singleton)` wasn't working at that time and that fixed it somehow)

So my final code in Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<IEventDataController, EventDataController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    var activator = new SimpleInjectorHubActivator(container);
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => activator);

    app.MapSignalR();
}
```